# Query to verify number 24 hours before the calling

Tags: postgresql

I have a table [POSTGRE] like this... 
 - Agent who answered the call, 
 - call number 
 - datetime end of call.

```
Agent   | Caller     |    DateTime   
------------------------------------
 101    | 555-1234  | 12-01-16 00:00
 101    | 555-1234  | 12-01-16 01:00 
 102    | 555-1234  | 12-01-16 02:00
 102    | 555-1234  | 13-01-16 06:00
```

1º - I need to verify each number (each line).. and look 24 hours before call, to check if is Recalling, eg.: day 13th was not recalling because the last call from this number was not in 24 hours.

2º - Need to get the agent from recalling.

need to display like this...

```
Agent   | Caller     |    DateTime   | Recalling |  Recalling-From
----------------------------------------------------------------------
 101    | 555-1234  | 12-01-16 00:00 | NO        | 
 101    | 555-1234  | 12-01-16 01:00 | YES       | 101
 102    | 555-1234  | 12-01-16 02:00 | YES       | 101
 102    | 555-1234  | 13-01-16 06:00 | NO        |
```

my query is ...

```
SELECT 
to_char(datahora_entrada_fila, 'DD/MM/YYYY') as dia,
calleridnum As numero,
MAX(datahora_inicio) AS data_ini
FROM callcenter.chamada_fila_in cfin
WHERE datahora_inicio BETWEEN '2016-12-01 00:00:00' AND '2016-12-01 23:59:59'
AND status_chamada  = 'Finalizada'
GROUP BY dia,numero

)

SELECT 
to_char(datahora_entrada_fila, 'DD/MM/YYYY') as dia,
(SELECT count(calleridnum) FROM callcenter.chamada_fila_in f INNER JOIN maiordata md ON f.calleridnum = md.numero WHERE calleridnum = cfin.calleridnum AND datahora_inicio BETWEEN md.data_ini - interval '24 hours' AND md.data_ini ) AS QtdRechamada,
calleridnum As numero
FROM callcenter.chamada_fila_in cfin
WHERE datahora_inicio BETWEEN '2016-12-01 00:00:00' AND '2016-12-01 23:59:59'
AND status_chamada  = 'Finalizada'
GROUP BY dia,numero
ORDER BY
dia,numero DESC
```

need a better function or method..
this query is very heavy in my database, need To be optimized.

Comment: `(DateTime - lag(DateTime) over (partition by Caller order by DateTime)) > '24 hours'::interval`

Comment: wonderfull... do you have the solution for the agents who called before 24 hours  (Recalling-From) column?

Comment: `lag(Agent)` Learn more about [window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html) - it is really interesting reading :o)

Comment: thanks for the help, I will read more !!!